# Unity3D & C# - Can't Jump Properly in my Game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I dont know what to do, when I click play, I click Space for Jump and sometime it jump but sometime it not. What do I do wrong?

i got it from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I_mjYhwSsS8

this is my PlayerController Script.

```
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    this.rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    Grounded();
    Jump();
    Move();
}

private void Jump()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && this.grounded)
    {
        this.rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * 4, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }
}

private void Grounded()
{
    if(Physics.CheckSphere(this.transform.position + Vector3.down, 0.2f, layerMask))
    {
        this.grounded = true;
    }
    else
    {
        this.grounded = false;
    }
    this.anim.SetBool("jump", !this.grounded);
}
private void Move()
{
    float verticalAxis = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    float horizontalAxis = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

    Vector3 movement = this.transform.forward * verticalAxis + this.transform.right * horizontalAxis;
    movement.Normalize();

    this.transform.position += movement * 0.04f;

    this.anim.SetFloat("vertical", verticalAxis);
    this.anim.SetFloat("horizontal", horizontalAxis);
}
```

Comment: There is no need for `this.` everywhere

Comment: May you help me? this is my  first time doing this T^T

Answer (score 0):

In general you want to get single time event user input within `Update`!

`FixedUpdate` is called in fixed time intervals, not every frame which might cause that if you press a button down exactly in a frame where `FixedUpdate` is **not** called you miss that event.

Secondly as soon as there is a rigidbody involved you should not use `Transform.position` to move it but rather go through the `Rigidbody` component either setting `velocity` or using `MovePosition`

```
private bool isJumpPressed;

private void Start()
{
    if(!rb) rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

private void Udpate()
{
    GetJumpInput();
}

private void GetJumpInput()
{
    // it is slightly more efficient to first check the simple bool flag 
    if(grounded && (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        // set the jump flag that is later handled in FixedUpdate
        isJumpPressed = true;
    }
}


private void FixedUpdate()
{
    Grounded();
    HandleJump();
    Move();
}

private void HandleJump()
{
    // since the grounded might have changed in the meantime check it again
    // then check and handle the jump flag
    if(grounded && isJumpPressed)
    {
        rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * 4, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }

    // after having handled the input always reset it
    isJumpPressed = false;
}

private void Grounded()
{
     grounded = Physics.CheckSphere(this.transform.position + Vector3.down, 0.2f, layerMask);
   
     anim.SetBool("jump", !this.grounded);
}

private void Move()
{
    // you might want to consider to only allow a change of this while on the ground
    // so midair you can't change the direction
    //if(!grounded) return;

    var verticalAxis = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    var horizontalAxis = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

    // store the current velocity
    var velocity = rb.velocity;
    // most importantly store the Y velocity in order to maintain that one
    var y = velocity.y;

    // instead of normalize you rather want to Clamp the magnitude
    // otherwise you also get magnitude 1 even though the input is actually smaller 
    velocity = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(rb.rotation * Vector3.forward * verticalAxis + rb.rotation * Vector3.right * horizontalAxis, 1) * 0.04f;
    // finally maintain the Y velocity so you can't fly ;)
    velocity.y = y;

    // and assign the velocity back to the rigidbody
    rb.velocity = velocity;

    this.anim.SetFloat("vertical", verticalAxis);
    this.anim.SetFloat("horizontal", horizontalAxis);
}
```